# decorate as_view() with extra context

Tags: python, django

I want to call class-based generic view with extra context from my method (view). Error that I get is `as_view() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)` . I'm using `django-userena`.

Code that executes this is:

```
return userena_views.ProfileListView.as_view(request,template_name='userena/profil.html', extra_context=projekti)
```

In urls.py I have this line:

```
url(r'^accounts/(?P<username>[\.\w-]+)', userena_views.ProfileListView.as_view(template_name='userena/profil.html', extra_context=Projekat.objects.all), name='userena_profile_list'),
```

Why are these two different? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is due to how [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#url) functions. you can use [kwargs to pass the parameters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#views-extra-options), and define a url pattern as follows:

```
url(r'^accounts/(?P<username>[\.\w-]+)', userena_views.ProfileListView.as_view(), name='userena_profile_list', kwargs={'template_name':'userena/profil.html', 'extra_context':Projekat.objects.all}),
```

---

**EDIT**

I misunderstood your question, sorry.
Then, trying to answer your question correctly... your code should be like this:

```
your_callable_view = userena_views.ProfileListView.as_view()
return your_callable_view(request, template_name='userena/profil.html', extra_context=projekti)
```

the reason is `ProfileListView.as_view()` returns a function that have to be called with parameters. `url()` do this for you, this is why it works in your ulrpatterns and not in your code. The only parameter as_view() is requiring is `self`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But, that works :) Decorating in my own view is the problem.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please let me know if it clarify your question

Comment: Thank you again. I have one more problem; I'm not getting a queryset as I did before when I called it from urls.py. That results in an almost blank HTML page.

Comment: it seems that `extra_context` in your code is `projekti` , whereas in your url is `Projekat.objects.all`. Maybe this is the reason? (I don't know how `projekti` has been defined)

Comment: Ok, I'm marking your answer as the answer, as it solved my first issue.

Answer (score 1):

Class based views can provide extra context data via a `get_context_data` method.

In the example below from the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/), `book_list` is added to the DetailView context.  The same method works for FormViews as well.

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from books.models import Book, Publisher

class PublisherDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Publisher

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
        context['book_list'] = Book.objects.all()
        return context
```